# How to display VCS path besides project name in NetBeans?

Tags: netbeans, version-control

In Eclipse there are options to configure the display of specific information related to a version control system like Subversion or Git as 'label decoration' besides the project name within its *Navigator* view.

[image: Label decorations in Eclipse's *Preferences* dialog]

**Is there something similar available in NetBeans?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realized now that it is possible to display such decorations via the menu *View* > *Show Versioning Labels*.

The labels can be adjusted within *Tools* > *Options* > *Team* > *Versioning* > <version control system> > <version control system> *Status Labels*.

Some description to this can be found in the [NetBeans documentation](https://netbeans.org/kb/docs/ide/subversion.html#fileStatus).

To get labels similar to the default ones in Eclipse I entered this as format:

```
{commit_revision} {date} {author} {folder}
```

In the options dialog this looks like this:

[image: Subversion Status Labels]

To further define how branches are displayed, you need to click on *Define {folder}...*

In the opening dialog I added the following entries:

```
.*?/(?<!/src/.{1,200})((branches|tags)/.+?)(/.*)?   \1
.*?/(?<!/src/.{1,200})trunk/.+                      trunk
```

See how it's looking in the dialog:

[image: Manage labels dialog]

This will display 'branches/foo' and 'tags/bar' for branches and tags and 'trunk' for the trunk.

Within the *Projects* view this will then look like this:

[image: Display of trunk within *Projects* view]

[image: Display of branch within *Projects* view]

Answer (score 14):

You can enable scm branch information in the project name:

`View` -> `Show versioning labels`

Comment: Thanks for the hint! That's really simple. I am wondering whether that option already existed in the version of NetBeans I used back then, though in 8.2 it works just fine.